# iOS MKMapView how to stop scrolling/moving while user pinching to zoom in

Tags: ios, mkmapview, uigesturerecognizer, apple-maps, uipinchgesturerecognizer

I have added a UIPinchGestureRecognizer to handle zoom in / out.
But while doing so map also starts moving and scrolling.
How to ignore this pan/scroll during pinching and catch only while user purposely scrolls using 1 finger.

One strange thing I observed is even if I drag the map with 1 finger, below delegate receives Pinch, Tap and Pan gestures

```
    - (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldBeRequiredToFailByGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
```

Returning No inside above delegate works well for pinch, but then it makes panning stuttering.

one more possibility is setting MapView scrollEnabled to NO, But then how can I control MapView scrolling/moving with pan gesture event handler?

Comment: Just disable the other gesture recognizers while pinching.

Comment: Pinch gesture is mixture of pinch and pan. So that won't help.